# Speeding subsetting of data.frame by row based conditions avoiding loops (dplyr, R)

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, tidyverse

I am new to `dplyr` and I am struggling with what I believe is a simple function. I have a dataset similar to:

```
require(dplyr)
dat <- data.frame(t = rep(seq(1, 5, 1),4), id = rep(c(rep("A",5), rep("B",5), rep("C",5), rep("D",5)), 1),
                  x = 1:20, y = 51:70, h = c(rep(1,10), rep(0,10) ) )
dat <- arrange(dat, t)
dat <- data.frame(dat, group = c("B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "D", "C", "A", "D", "C", "A", "A", "C", "C", "B") )
dat
```

I would like to attach a new column to the dataset `dat` containing the following operation:

1. for each row, for example row 3 with `id == C`, take the remaining rows such that their values in `group` is different to the starting `id`, that is C in this case
2. group the observations by time `t`
3. perform the following operation if the `id` (in this case the `id` C in row 3) has value `1` in col `h`: sum all the values (from the group based on `t`) in `x` and divide by the standard deviation of the values in `y` and `x` (from the group based on `t`). If `id` has a value of `0` in col `h` place a `0`. If there are no observations the code should place a zero.

For example, for `id` `A` in row `1` the code should produce a `0` because all observations at time `t == 1` have `group == A`. For `id` `B` in row `2` the code should produce `(11 + 16) / sd(c(11, 16, 61, 66))`.

How to perform this on `dplyr` or anyother way that does not include `looping`? Thank you.

The data looks like

```
dat
#    t id  x  y h group
# 1  1  A  1 51 1     B
# 2  1  B  6 56 1     A
# 3  1  C 11 61 0     A
# 4  1  D 16 66 0     A
# 5  2  A  2 52 1     A
# 6  2  B  7 57 1     B
# 7  2  C 12 62 0     C
# 8  2  D 17 67 0     D
# 9  3  A  3 53 1     A
# 10 3  B  8 58 1     B
# 11 3  C 13 63 0     D
# 12 3  D 18 68 0     C
# 13 4  A  4 54 1     A
# 14 4  B  9 59 1     D
# 15 4  C 14 64 0     C
# 16 4  D 19 69 0     A
# 17 5  A  5 55 1     A
# 18 5  B 10 60 1     C
# 19 5  C 15 65 0     C
# 20 5  D 20 70 0     B
```

I tried the following but it does not produce the correct result.

```
dat %>% 
  group_by(t) %>% 
  mutate(new = ifelse(id != group, h * (sum(x) /map_dbl(row_number(), ~ 
      sd(c(x[-.x], y[-.x]) ))) , 0) )
```

Comment: If you're after speed, I would suggest the `data.table` package.

Comment: I need to perform this type of operations on a very large dataset and several times. Plus, I would like to bootstrap the whole estimation procedure so speed is important. Unfortunately, I know little of `dplyr` (which seems much faster than `apply` or `for-loop`), but I know even less of `data.table`. How would you set this on `data.table`?

Answer (score 1):

This should just illustrate speed performance of `data.tables` vs `dplyr`. I just took the whole ifelse of the mutate and packed it in a data.table operation and grouped with (`by = t`). So the results will not be the desired ones, but the results are at least the same for dplyr and data.tables.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

datDT <- data.table(dat)

DTF <- function(){
  d <- datDT[ , new := ifelse(  id != group, h * (sum(x) /
                      map_dbl(row_number(x), ~ 
                                sd(c(x[-.x], y[-.x])))) , 0) , by = t]
  d
}
DPF <- function(){
  d <- dat %>% 
    group_by(t) %>% 
    mutate(new = ifelse(id != group, h * (sum(x) /map_dbl(row_number(x), ~ 
                                                            sd(c(x[-.x], y[-.x]) ))) , 0) )
  d
}

dtres = DTF()
dplres = DPF()

all.equal(dtres, data.table(dplres))


library(microbenchmark)
mc <- microbenchmark(times = 100,
                     DT =  DTF(),
                     DPLYR = DPF()
)

mc
```

---

> ```
> Unit: milliseconds
>   expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval cld
>     DT  7.428605  7.821919  8.324179  8.056762  8.429851 15.39028   100  a 
>  DPLYR 11.154076 11.439025 11.895716 11.720050 12.139022 16.40934   100   b
> ```

The gain is not huge, but still noticeable and I'm sure there is still some optimization that can be done with setting keys, getting rid of the ifelse etc, but I leave that to the real data.table experts :).

So if you're new to both, maybe dig into data.tables, since you can also use dplyr-verbs with them (*like below*) and be slightly faster than with `tbl` structures.

```
dtres %>% 
  group_by(t) %>% 
  summarise(mN = mean(new))
```